# Are there infinitely many mechanical systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Are there infinitely many mechanical systems? And can we say anything about the cardinality of perturbations of a mechanical system?

Answer (score 2):

"Are there infinitely many mechanical systems? " Yes, think of a pendulum, when you change the length you change the system. So there are infinite many type of pendulum thus many mechanical systems.

"the cardinality of perturbations of a mechanical system" You need to explain what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

If we restrict ourselves to small perturbations then the possible perturbations of a mechanical system form a vector space. As pointed out in other answers, the *cardinality* of this vector space is infinite. However, if you are actually asking about the *dimension* of this vector space (which is a more useful measure of the “size” of a vector space than its cardinality) then this is given by the [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics)) of the mechanical system.

Comment: I think that rather than saying the cardinality is infinite, we should say that the cardinality is $|\mathbb{R}|$, the cardinality of the continuum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum